# Module Error for some content types but not for others

Tags: 7, meta-tags

**The Error**

> warning: array_keys() [function.array-keys]: The first argument should be an array in /home/vermontbiz/webapps/vermontbiz/modules/int_meta/int_meta_cck.module on line 39.
>   warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/vermontbiz/webapps/vermontbiz/modules/int_meta/int_meta_cck.module on line 39.

**The Code**

```
function function int_meta_cck_int_meta($op, &$arg) {
  switch ($op) {
    case 'load': {
      if (!empty($arg->int_meta)) {
        $supported = int_meta_cck_supported($arg->type);
        foreach ($arg->int_meta as $key => $tag) {
          if (in_array($tag->field, $supported)) {
            $parts = explode('.', $tag->field);
            if (isset($arg->{$parts[0]})) {
             foreach ($arg->{$parts[0]} as $tmp) {
               $arg->int_meta[$key]->values[] = $tmp[$parts[1]];
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    } 
    break;

    case 'fields': {
      return int_meta_cck_supported($arg);
    }
    break;
  }
}

function int_meta_cck_supported($arg) {
  $fields = array();
  if (!empty($arg)) {
    $type = content_types($arg);
    if (!empty($type)) {
      foreach ($type['fields'] as $name => $info) {

      //**Error below takes place in the line below but doesn't effect all content**

        foreach (array_keys($info['widget']['default_value'][0]) as $col) {
          $fields[] = $name . '.' . $col;
        }
      }
    }
  } 
return $fields; }
```

My question is why does the line give an error to some content types but not others?

The two content types.

[image: This content type works with the module]

[image: This content type doesn't work with the module]

Comment: LINE 22 didn't make it into question

Comment: Compare the field types of your content types. Do all that produce this error share a common field or field type? If yes, which one? Also sounds like something you should report as a bug for that int_meta module.

Comment: A side note: It seems that you have placed contributed/custom modules in the top level modules directory. You should not do that. Instead, place them in sites/all/modules.

Comment: Why is that? Could that be an issue?

Comment: No, not for that issue. But modules/ is reserved for core modules. It will make upgrading to another major version unecessary complicated for example.

Answer (score 1):

You're making an assumption and that is that

```
$info['widget']['default_value'][0]
```

Will always be an array. My guess is that for some fields (depending on configuration) that `$info['widget']['default_value'][0]` will be either `NULL`, `FALSE` or a scalar value.

Comment: There are differences in the field types.

Comment: Can I paste images in the comments?

Comment: @Nick, no, but you can edit your original question and add them there.

Comment: Well I found a module that worked much better. Thanks @Berdir for all your help.